# How can I integrate google graphs at an AMP page?

Tags: mobile, graph, google-visualization, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Google provides its Javascript APIs for Google Graphs, but I cannot write any js on page as it is an AMP page

I have following solutions:
Make a different non AMP page, integrate google graphs there and add an iframe of the page on my AMP page, but my page is on HTTP and google does not allows HTTP iframe link on AMP Page.

Can anyone think of any other solution?

It would be great if you could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed Map with Marker on AMP HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135971/embed-map-with-marker-on-amp-html-page)

Comment: adding a new tag.

Comment: can't you just include the needed js in a separate file? --> `<script async src="draw-charts.js"></script>`

Comment: No, google does not allows to load any external JS files directly on the AMP page.

Answer (score 2):

amp-iframe is the correct approach in this case. You have two options:

1. serve the iframe from a different origin which support https, e.g. using [firebase static hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/).
2. use the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) attribute to directly embed the iframe content into your AMP:

   <amp-iframe width="500" height="281"
     layout="responsive"
     sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups"
     allowfullscreen
     frameborder="0"
     srcdoc="<h1>Hello</h1>">
   </amp-iframe>